# How to show app bar above the phone gallery?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

[gallery image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUzJK.jpg)

I need to show the app bar above the 'Recent' file [ Recent file shown in the above image ] and the bottom navigation bar at the end of the screen. I'm using the image_picker package to pick images from the gallery. Please help me to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: That's the part of android gallery which you can't change, but you can make your own custom listing by fetching files paths for android.

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the image selector. The design depends on your phone.